# Adding custom header to specific files in a directory

Tags: linux, perl

I would like to add a unique one line header that pertains to each file FOCUS*.tsv file in a specified directory.  After that, I would like to combine all of these files into one file.

First I’ve tried `sed` command.

```
`my $cmd9 = `sed -i '1i$SampleID[4]' $tsv_file`;` print $cmd9;
```

It looked like it worked but after I’ve combined all of these files into one file in the next section of the code, the inserted row was listed four times for each file.

I’ve tried the following Perl script to accomplish the same but it deleted the content of the file and only prints out the added header.

I’m looking for the simplest way to accomplish what I’m looking for.
Here is what I’ve tried.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my $home="/data/";                                                     
my $tsv_directory = $home."test_all_runs/".$ARGV[0];
my $tsvfiles = $home."test_all_runs/".$ARGV[0]."/tsv_files.txt";

my @run_directory = (); @run_directory = split /\//, $tsv_directory; print "The run directory is #############".$run_directory[3]."\n";

my $cmd = `ls $tsv_directory/FOCUS*\.tsv > $tsvfiles`; #print "$cmd";
my $cmda = "ls $tsv_directory/FOCUS*\.tsv > $tsvfiles"; #print "$cmda";

my @tsvfiles =();
#this code opens the vcf_files.txt file and passes each line into an array for indidivudal manipulation
open(TXT2, "$tsvfiles");
        while (<TXT2>){  
                push (@tsvfiles, $_);   
                }
close(TXT2);

foreach (@tsvfiles){
        chop($_);
}

#this loop works fine
for my $tsv_file (@tsvfiles){

      open my $in, '>', $tsv_file or die "Can't write new file: $!";    
      open my $out, '>', "$tsv_file.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";  

    $tsv_file =~ m|([^/]+)-oncomine.tsv$| or die "Can't extract Sample ID";
    my $sample_id = $1;
    #print "The sample ID is ############## $sample_id\n";
    my $headerline = $run_directory[3]."/".$sample_id;
    print $out $headerline;
    while( <$in> ) {
    print $out $_;
    }

    close $out;
    close $in;

unlink($tsv_file);
rename("$tsv_file.new", $tsv_file);

}
```

Thank you

Comment: (1) Is this code exactly what you run?  You open the `$in` file with `>`, so for writing.  Should be `<` for reading.  Otherwise, the code you show should indeed prepend a line. (2) How do you want to "_combine_" these files? // There are other things that can be improved.

Comment: I've changed `$in to `$in, '<',` and it worked. However, when I ran the code that combines the files, each header row appeared four times. (2) I combine specific rows and columns from each file. Each file is exactly the same format, so I loop through an array of files and append one after another. Without the added headers it works great. thanks

Comment: For example, I exclude rows with CNV|intronic|synonymous|utr_3|utr_5 and only interested in particular columns that I modify before appending to the final file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  If you need some code for that as well, I can add it to the answer below but then I would need it a bit more precise.  What I posted are comments on the rest of the code, along with the statement from my comment above about the actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the wrong `'>'` when opening the file for *reading* was the problem and it got solved.

However, I'd like to make a few comments on some of the rest of the code.

- The list of files is built by running external `ls` redirected to a file, then reading this file into an array. However, that is exactly the job of [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) and all of that is replaced by

  ```
  my @tsvfiles = glob "$tsv_directory/FOCUS*.tsv";
  ```

  Then you don't need the `chomp` either, and the `chop` that is used would actually hurt since it removes the last *character*, not only the newline (or really `$/`).
- Use of [`chop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) is probably not what you want. If you are removing the linefeed (`$/`) use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)
- To extract a match and assign it, a common idiom is

  ```
  my ($sample_id) = $tsv_file =~ m|([^/]+)-oncomine.tsv$| 
      or die "Can't extract Sample ID: $!";
  ```

  Note that I also added `$!`, to actually print the error. Otherwise we just don't know what it was.
- The `unlink` and `rename` appear to be overwriting one file with another. You can do that by using `move` from the core module [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html)

  ```
  use File::Copy qw(move);
  move ($tsv_file_new, $tsv_file)  
      or die "Can't move $tsv_file to $tsv_file_new: $!";
  ```

  which renames the `_new` into `$tsv_file`, so overwriting it.

---

As for how the files need to be combined, more precise explanation would be needed.